# C++ Memory profiler in Visual Studio: why do most of allocations end in the void category?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-profiling

I tried the Visual Studio memory profiler on my application to quickly review which objects (dynamically allocated in various STL containers) has the strongest impact on memory consumption.

After taking the snapshot, I realized that most of the allocations are identified as the type `void`. That is very impractical, as I have to sort out the allocations by myself (using the `view instances` button).

Is this a normal behavior, or could I take some measure to sort out those allocations depending on the type or code location automatically?

Comment: `most of the allocations are identified as the type void` Can you provide a detailed description? Do you mean void pointer?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I read it as void pointer. In the listing, it's just `void`.